# What is meant by slots and signals in Qt classes?

Tags: c++, qt, oop

I was going through a `Qt` tutorial [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html), when I came across this following piece of code:

```
 #include <QObject>

 class Counter : public QObject
 {
     Q_OBJECT

 public:
     Counter() { m_value = 0; }

     int value() const { return m_value; }

 public slots:
     void setValue(int value);

 signals:
     void valueChanged(int newValue);

 private:
     int m_value;
 };
```

Can anyone explain to me what is the usage of the `public slots`, `signals` within the declaration? I though there are only two, `public` and `private`. What are they called, and what is their usage?

Comment: @Cupidvogel: huh, I've missed a link. So, you'd better to read that doc once more... it is Qt basics that you ought to clearly understand. And the official documentation is pretty clear about it.

Comment: Looks like it. Better close the question, will you, Barry?

Comment: It needs 3 more close votes for that.

Comment: @Cupidvogel In addition to the document, [**this article**](http://woboq.com/blog/how-qt-signals-slots-work.html) depicts the  Signal & Slot mechanism under the hood in detail, worth reading.

Answer (score 3):

> Signals and slots is a language construct introduced in Qt for
>   communication between objects[1] which makes it easy to implement the
>   Observer pattern while avoiding boilerplate code. The concept is that
>   GUI widgets can send signals containing event information which can be
>   received by other controls using special functions known as slots.
>
> The signal/slot system fits well with the way Graphical User
>   Interfaces are designed. Similarly, the signal/slot system can be used
>   for other non-GUI usages, for example asynchronous I/O (including
>   sockets, pipes, serial devices, etc.) event notification or to
>   associate timeout events with appropriate object instances and methods
>   or functions. It is easy to use and no
>   registration/deregistration/invocation code need to be written,
>   because Qt's Meta Object Compiler (MOC) automatically generates the
>   needed infrastructure.
>
> A commonly used metaphor is a spreadsheet. A spreadsheet has cells
>   that observe the source cell(s). When the source cell is changed, the
>   dependent cells are updated from the event.

Not bad explained from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signals_and_slots)

---

Since Qt basically invented the concept it would be best for you to actually read the article you posted in your question.

Especially:

> Signals
>
> Signals are emitted by an object when its internal state has changed
>   in some way that might be interesting to the object's client or owner.
>   Only the class that defines a signal and its subclasses can emit the
>   signal.
>
> When a signal is emitted, the slots connected to it are usually
>   executed immediately, just like a normal function call. When this
>   happens, the signals and slots mechanism is totally independent of any
>   GUI event loop. Execution of the code following the emit statement
>   will occur once all slots have returned. The situation is slightly
>   different when using queued connections; in such a case, the code
>   following the emit keyword will continue immediately, and the slots
>   will be executed later.
>
> If several slots are connected to one signal, the slots will be
>   executed one after the other, in the order they have been connected,
>   when the signal is emitted.
>
> Signals are automatically generated by the moc and must not be
>   implemented in the .cpp file. They can never have return types (i.e.
>   use void).
>
> A note about arguments: Our experience shows that signals and slots
>   are more reusable if they do not use special types. If
>   QScrollBar::valueChanged() were to use a special type such as the
>   hypothetical QScrollBar::Range, it could only be connected to slots
>   designed specifically for QScrollBar. Connecting different input
>   widgets together would be impossible.

and

> Slots
>
> A slot is called when a signal connected to it is emitted. Slots are
>   normal C++ functions and can be called normally; their only special
>   feature is that signals can be connected to them.
>
> Since slots are normal member functions, they follow the normal C++
>   rules when called directly. However, as slots, they can be invoked by
>   any component, regardless of its access level, via a signal-slot
>   connection. This means that a signal emitted from an instance of an
>   arbitrary class can cause a private slot to be invoked in an instance
>   of an unrelated class.
>
> You can also define slots to be virtual, which we have found quite
>   useful in practice.
>
> Compared to callbacks, signals and slots are slightly slower because
>   of the increased flexibility they provide, although the difference for
>   real applications is insignificant. In general, emitting a signal that
>   is connected to some slots, is approximately ten times slower than
>   calling the receivers directly, with non-virtual function calls. This
>   is the overhead required to locate the connection object, to safely
>   iterate over all connections (i.e. checking that subsequent receivers
>   have not been destroyed during the emission), and to marshall any
>   parameters in a generic fashion. While ten non-virtual function calls
>   may sound like a lot, it's much less overhead than any new or delete
>   operation, for example. As soon as you perform a string, vector or
>   list operation that behind the scene requires new or delete, the
>   signals and slots overhead is only responsible for a very small
>   proportion of the complete function call costs.
>
> The same is true whenever you do a system call in a slot; or
>   indirectly call more than ten functions. On an i586-500, you can emit
>   around 2,000,000 signals per second connected to one receiver, or
>   around 1,200,000 per second connected to two receivers. The simplicity
>   and flexibility of the signals and slots mechanism is well worth the
>   overhead, which your users won't even notice.
>
> Note that other libraries that define variables called signals or
>   slots may cause compiler warnings and errors when compiled alongside a
>   Qt-based application. To solve this problem, #undef the offending
>   preprocessor symbol.